# Player not moving in Unity what could be cause this?

Tags: c#, frame-rate

im trying to make a fps game following a tutorial code seems to be correct but my character wont move any idea why?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOLze.png)

cant embed links yet so it added links sorry

Comment: [link] https://i.stack.imgur.com/jP42l.png [link2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVA8l.png [link3] https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOLze.png